# Cannot create new system call on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi

I am trying to create a system call in Raspberry Pi's latest kernel source version 4.1.17. I have followed these steps:

- increased the number in `arch/arm/include/asm/unistd.h`
- created a entry CALL in `arch/arm/kernel/calls.S` as `CALL(sys_helloworld)` at the end of the file.
- created  `#define __NR_helloworld (__NR_SYSCALL_BASE+388)` in `arch/arm/include/uapi/asm/unistd.h`
- added definition in `include/linux/syscalls.h`
- finally implemented the syscall in `arch/arm/kernel/sys_arm.c` with the name `sys_helloworld`

After cross-compiling, it says:

> arch/arm/kernel/entry-common.S:108: Error: __NR_syscalls is not equal to the size of the syscall table.

Am I still missing something to be done in `entry-commons.S`?

**EDIT** : I have compilation issue resolved by adding extra numbers in `arch/arm/include/asm/unistd.h`. Earlier this number was 388. After adding a system call I had to increase it to 392. [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554267/extending-the-rasbian-kernel-linux-kernel-3-10-28-for-arm-raspberry-pi-how) suggests that this is due to padding in syscall table. Is there any way to know what exact number to increase after adding system call? I did it by trial and error and it compiled.

Comment: Got the answer of the EDIT. Value of the padding is calculated at the end of calls.S based on the number of system call. It can also be manually determined after seeing the logic and number can be added in unistd.h